# Help understanding the difference between imperative and logical conditionals?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

How would you define a truth set $A$: for all $x \in B$ that satisfies $Q(x)$ where $B$ is another truth set that satisfies $P(x)$? I'm trying to formalize the natural intuition of *if-then* as distinct from *modus ponens*.

My attempts:

1. Let $B = \{\,y\;|\;P(y)\,\}$ and $A = \{x\in B\;|\;Q(x)\,\}$
2. Let $A = \{\,x\in \{\;y\;|\;P(y)\,\}\;|\;Q(x)\,\}$

Are (1) and (2) correct with respect to the definition I gave above? Are (1) and (2) equivalent? Is there an even better way to reduce (2)? Did I successfully entail the notion that in order for Q to even be considered that P must first be true? Could you remark on the differences between this form of a conditional and that of *modus ponens* and quantified conditionals, in general? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using set-theoretic notation, which is usually interpreted according to standard set theory. In that case, no you did not "entail the notion that in order for Q to even be considered that P must first be true".

Both the sets you defined are exactly the same sets, by the extensionality axiom. Thus there is no difference between them and $\{ x : P(x) \land Q(x) \}$.

In standard set theory (which is used in almost all of mathematics), you can only define properties using first-order formulae, and the intended domain of the set theory is the 'universe' of all sets, so if you managed to define a property $Q$ in the first place, $Q(x)$ would be well-defined for any set $x$, and there is no need to **first** require $P(x)$ to hold before testing $Q(x)$.

But there are alternative formal systems that are different from the standard set theory. Most of them are type theories of some sort, and most type theories **syntactically** require properties to be about **previously** typed objects. So you could construct a type that accepts only the objects that are firstly of type $B$ and then secondly satisfying $Q$. Depending on the specific system, it might be able to express the notion that $Q(x)$ is only required to be syntactically valid in the case when $x$ is of type $B$. You would want to read up about dependent type theories.

Now why should we even consider type theories, since almost all mathematics can be translated into the standard set theory (ZFC or extensions of it)? It is simply because a lot of mathematics is actually done informally and mathematicians have an innate type-theoretic intuition. If you are not familiar with set theory, you would never consider "$\mathbb{N} \in 3$" as a meaningful question. Similarly, you would never write the function notation "$f(x)$" unless $f$ is in the current context already proven to be a function and $x$ is already proven to be in its domain. These intuitive notions are completely captured by type-theoretic syntax rules, and not by standard set theory.

Some type theories are interpretable in ZFC, meaning that there is a way to translate statements in such a theory $T$ into statements in ZFC such that any statement that can be proven in $T$ can also be proven in ZFC. This property would imply that if we believe the consistency of ZFC (it cannot be proven if it is true), then we are justified in believing the consistency of $T$, and so if $T$ 'makes more intuitive sense' then we can go ahead in using $T$ for all our everyday mathematical work. This is exactly what most mathematicians (who are not set theorists or logicians) do in practice. I read a published article describing in significant detail the usual type theory that most mathematicians unconsciously work in, but I can't recall where it is at the moment.

Comment: And if you know programming, what you are asking for is like short-circuiting logical operators. Standard set theory has nothing of that sort, but some other formal systems such as dependent type theories do.

Comment: Well, in a way, it does entail that notion, though doesn't it? Consider your correction: $\{x | P(x) \land Q(x)\}$. It does not matter if Q(x) if not P(x), and vice-versa. The vacuous truths have been eliminated, and it appears that the intuitive notion of "for all x, if P(x) is true then Q(x) is true", which is so close yet so far away from modus ponens and the conditional laws, e.g. $\{x | \neg P(x) \lor Q(x)\}$.

Comment: @Holographic: I'm not sure what you're referring to as "does entail that notion", nor "so close yet so far". Please be more precise.

Comment: @Holographic: Either your sets are **equal** to the one I stated, or they are not. If you say they are, then they have exactly the **same properties**, so they entail exactly the same notions. Of course, you're free to choose whichever you feels conveys what you want better, but they are still identical. If you say they are not, then you are not using standard set theory, which is fine only if you have a proper alternative formal system that supports your desired distinction.

Comment: This exploration began because it doesn't make sense to me that we include all $x$ in the truth set that satisfy $\neg P(x)$ when we write $P(x)\implies Q(x)$, as I was conflating the notion of logical implication with an actual conditional. Modus ponens is far from being an actual conditional because it allows for vacuous truths. If $P(x)$ is true then it is *implied* in $\{x|\neg P(x) \lor Q(x)\}$ that $Q(x)$ is true. This means that if $x$ is included when $P(x)$ is both true or false, which would be absolutely wrong in semantics for conditionals for programming languages.

Comment: @Holographic: So if you're indeed looking from a programming-based perspective, you definitely should look up dependent type theory. In standard set theory there is no such thing. Also, in programming you have non-halting programs, but first-order logic does not have such a notion, because it is intended to capture truths, not processes

Comment: @Holographic: I mentioned dependent type theory because you were talking about collections in your question, and that is one natural way of capturing type-checking, which is what you are talking about. If you care about the more fundamental question of truth values, then look at Kleene's three-valued logic (which is only propositional though). There you would be able to distinguish$\def\imp{\rightarrow}$ between the conditional $P \imp Q \equiv \neg P \lor Q$ and $(P=true) \imp (Q=true) \equiv (P\ne true) \lor (Q=true)$. If $(P,Q) = (null,null)$, the first is null while the second is true.

Comment: Also just found some related concepts that connect to my question. They are negation as failure (NAF) and Autoepistemic semantics:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure

Comment: @Holographic: Yes there are many many different kinds of formal systems. You've to decide which one suits the desired usage better. For your question, negation as failure just isn't suitable. There is also intuitionistic logic and the Brouwer-Heyting-Kolmogorov interpretation, but since these are strictly weaker than classical logic, they aren't what you really want. You want type-checking, which I too think is beneficial, since most mathematics are informally typed, and it is sufficient to have syntactic overlay over standard set theory. Also see "and then" and "or else" in Ada syntax.